# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' - using Web Deploy, EF Code First, Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

Visual Studio 2012 Express, EF5, Code First Migrations, Web Publish.

I am doing a web publish from a Windows 8 Laptop to a Windows Server 2008 R2 web server using Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2012.

The files are uploaded fine. But I get this error:
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

When Code first tries to create the database.

The Web Publishing wizard uses a windows user to login - that user has db_owner permissions on the master database.

Exactly what do I need to do to grant CREATE DATABASE permissions? (or see which user tried to do it - the error doesn't report that for some reason?!).

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just come across this problem and I resolved it following the instructions [here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/14/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx). Effectively, the "IIS APPPool\DefaultAppPool" user must first be added. While adding it, ensure that 
as its "Server Roles" it is a "sysadmin".

Comment: This is fine for test servers, but I wouldn't advise that in production - a vulnerability in one of your web applications or in IIS itself could be made much worse if the process is sysadmin on your db.

Comment: You can remove the permission after the db is created. It's enough by the way to use only dbcreator role.

Answer (score 1):

If you'r running the application from IIS, then IIS APPPOOL\{Your apppool name} is the sql user trying to create the db. If there is no such user in you sql server then create one with the name IIS APPPOOL\{Your apppool name} and give server role dbcreator, public and sysadmin. Now I hope you won't see the error, code first should create the db.

Comment: But what if you want to deploy a website that has READ-ONLY access to the database? I am forced NOT to use secrets.json just so I can specifically say I want to connect to my database using a read-only account. Frustrating